# Woocommerce does not use language file to full extent

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As suggested [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/), I have uploaded the latest [stable German release](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/de/default) in *.mo format to my Wordpress installation in the folder wp-content/languages/woocommerce. The file name is woocommerce-de_DE.mo.

Unfortunately, Woocommerce uses this translation file only partially. Nearly all words on the cart page for example remain in English.

What should I do in order to let Woocommerce use my language file properly and everywhere on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Usually theme translation takes several .po and .mo files:

1. Theme
2. Plugins
3. Wordpress

It seems like I only had translated the WooCommerce plugin, which isn't enough to have everything translated. **You need to take the theme's .pot file located in the theme's languages folder and apply necessary translations there as well.**

WooCommerce + Theme translation should cover most of the translation needs.